# airmon-ng is giving a black screen

Tags: networking, 13.04, broadcom, aircrack-ng

I have Ubuntu 13.04
Broadcom bcm43142

When I run `sudo airmon-ng` or `airmon-ng wlan0`, it shows a black screen.

[image]

I can't type anything using the keyboard. I tried reinstalling, but got the same result. I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu. I can't even switch screens or try any shortcuts to remove the black screen.

Comment: It's not `sudo airmon-ng` or `airmon-ng wlan0`, it's supposed to be `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`. What do you mean you get a black screen? As in, the terminal is not responding? Or your whole screen turns black? Why can't you take a screenshot of it?

Comment: uploaded the screenshot of it and i also tried the command you suggested above got the same result.

Comment: Oh, like **that**. It seems like others face this too ([here](http://askubuntu.com/q/271947/52726), [here (arch linux though)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=108104), and [here (Backtrack)](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=11835)). It seems to be a Broadcom/Atheros thing, and I'm guessing you have Broadcom because the dump screen shows the `wl` module. Try fully updating your machine (sudo apt-get dist-upgrade) and update/change the wireless driver. Take a look at the BROADCOM WIRELESS 43142 section in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/52726).